# How to draw lines like below image in android

Tags: android

Hello I want to draw like below lines in android. What is the way to do this or is there any library to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You want answer for all the layout? or only for below lines??

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are talking about the two gray sort rectangular shapes.

So what you can do is create an xml files in the drawbles folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

Let us say you save it as rectanlge.xml

Then from in your layout

```
    <View
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>
```

This would create a rectangle shape

Ready to answer any further questions

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by drawing view for example It will draw Silver gray colored Line.

```
 <View
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
```

Note :- Please update height & width section values as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit the layout file your activity uses. In the place you want to add the lines add this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#30000000"/>
```

This will create a "line" with the given `layout_width` and `layout_height` and the color set on the `background` attribute.

In case you want to make your lines expand on the whole screen (horizontally) you can use this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#30000000"/>
```

Then you can use `layout_margin` or `layout_marginRight` to change it's shape.